# how to find the sum of a series with finite items here?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to calculate $\sum_{k=i}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k-1}\frac{1}{mk+1}$, where k is not 1. Does anyone some skills?

Comment: There is a solution but it involves the digamma function or harmonic numbers which, I suppose, you would not enjoy.

Comment: Yeah, I tried Mathematica and got digamma function. Thanks anyway! In fact, I am interested in how the sum depends on i but we can't take derivative, right?